# Same query parameter multiple time FastAPI 0.100.x and pydantic v2 fails pattern validation

Tags: fastapi, pydantic, python-3.10

I encountered the following problem, when upgrading from pydantic 1.10 and fastapi 0.99.1 to pydantic 2.0.2 and fastapi 0.100.x:

FastAPI offers the capability, to have multiple query parameters with the same name collected into one list.

```
from fastapi import Query
from typing import Annotated

@app.post("/my/endpoint") # being a post operation is due to the later coming implementation
async def my_endpoint_function(list_with_query_values: Annotated[list[str], Query(pattern=REGEX_EXPR)]): pass
```

I abstracted some information, so that it is more tangible (functionality exactly the same, just other names).

The problem is, that if I run the same code with pydantic v2, the validation of the list[str] part breaks and I get a TypeError. As far as I understand it, the problem is, that pydantic v2 does different validation procedures for nested types, but I don't get my head around on how to get it running with pydantic v2, to validate every str with the given pattern. It now validates the list, and ignores the nested str (if i understood the error messages right).

I tried to look through the migration guide (https://docs.pydantic.dev/dev-v2/migration/) and also look through the github issue with pydantic v2 (https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/9710) but was not able to find any information about it.

Next step would be, that i look further into fastapi, if there is another ways to handle query parameters, but i would like to avoid that, as i like the simplicity of the current approach. Also the example on the fastapi documentation do it the same way...

Answer (score 0):

Your issue relates to a breaking change to [Generic Validated Collections](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/validators/#generic-validated-collections). For V2, you need to either annotate the type within the container (here, using `constr`), or create the type and then reference in the container.

#### Annotate type, the reference in container:

*This comes close to solving your problem*

```py
from typing import List
from typing_extensions import Annotated

from fastapi import Query
from pydantic import TypeAdapter


# Annotate your type
query_value = Annotated[str, Query(pattern="[A-z]+")]
list_with_query_values = List[query_value]

# Test it out with typeadaptor
ta = TypeAdapter(list_with_query_values)
ta.validate_python(["hello", "abc-123"])
```

#### Annotate the type within the container:

This is more direct, but doesn't give you other specific FastAPI features:

```py
from pydantic.types import constr

# List of strings with constrained type
list_with_query_values = List[constr(pattern="[A-z]+")]
```